# PHPExcel - Fatal Error - Allowed memory size - Альтернатива для RAM

Tags: php, excel

Важный вопрос! Так как на хостинге выделено не больше 128МБайт оперативной памяти, я не могу обрабатывать большие Excel-файлы.

Собственно мне надо конвертировать любой Excel-файл в CSV. Но при весьма больших объёмах данных PHP-сценарию не хватает оперативной памяти.

Основное правило: memory_limit устанавливается только в php.ini и никак иначе установить не получиться.

Собственно вот код:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

require_once "./class/PHPExcel.php";

$source = $_GET['source']; // large.csv = 42M or large.xlsx = 15M

// Установка метода всё равно не снимает использование RAM-машины
$method = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$arguments = ["cacheMemorySize" => "1024M"];
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($method, $arguments);

$type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($source);
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($type);
// Результат после выполнения : $reader->load("large.csv");
// FATAL ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
// allocate 32 bytes) in [path_to_class]/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 550
//
// Результат после выполнения : $reader->load("large.xlsx");
// FATAL ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
// allocate 218235205 bytes) in /home/max/localhost/html/class/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php
// on line 327

/*$excel = */
$reader->load($source);

?>
```

А вот собственно и сам ВОПРОС(ы):

1. **Как установить вместо использования RAM - указанную папку?** (например ./temp/)
2. **Возможно ли это сделать?**

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [SimpleExcel](https://github.com/faisalman/simple-excel-php), он гораздо менее требователен к ресурсам сервера.

PHPExcel использовать в столь ограниченных ресурсах тоже можно, но несколько сложнее. Например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817651/phpexcel-runs-out-of-256-512-and-also-1024mb-of-ram) есть несколько советов как читать файл поэтапно, только нужные колонки и т.п. что влечёт меньший расход ОЗУ. Использовать же папку вместо RAM - однозначно нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

И так нельзя?

echo ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
echo ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";

в PHP нет такого, чтобы вместо памяти использовать папку на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_discISAM;
$cacheSettings = array( 
    'dir' => '/temp'
);
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
```

но это все равно не поможет, PHPExcel жрет память десятками мегабайт даже с настройками кэширования в файл! эта библиотека - кошмар программиста.
попробуйте другую:
https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter
обещают:

> Never run out of memory with PHPExcel again.